# The type User was not mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am implementing o-auth in my mvc4 web application. but when I log in using external login (Microsoft)
it gives error in my Account model.

> The type User was not mapped.

my Account model is-

```
 public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection") //Exception raise here
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

User is database generated model class. I have seen  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427803/the-type-was-not-mapped) but no help. same exception is raising every time.

my Connection string is-

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=URLofWebsite;Initial Catalog=gestest;User ID=Username;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding it again?

Comment: Do you have an `IdentityModels.cs` file in your root level Models folder? If so, can you please post the code in there? I would also check your model with your database to make sure they match. It's having a problem linking your model to what it thinks is in the database.